# PHP calling a method and checking return simultaneously

Tags: php, if-statement, fclose

I'm new the PHP, and had a very simple question. I've seen people call and return statements in the conditional of the if statement. For example

```
if ($connection = @ssh2_connect($host, 22)) { do something };
```

If I am not wrong this will check the return boolean as well as create the connection. Will this work for everything? More specifically, for `fclose()`, I want to know if I do something like this:

```
if (fclose($stream)) { do something };
```

will actually close the check the boolean return value of it AND close the stream. Or do I have to do this?

```
...
fclose($stream);
if (fclose($stream)) { do something };  
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
if (fclose($stream)) { do something };
```

and it will work, but probably not like you think. The stream is closed first, then the result of that function, a boolean, is checked by the `if` statement.

Look at it in another way: The `if` statement only cares about `TRUE` or `FALSE` so it evaluated anything inside its brackets. If this happens to be a function that closes a stream, so be it.

Note that `TRUE` is simply everything that is not `FALSE` and `FALSE` can also be things like zero (`0` or `'0'`),`''`, `NULL`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so basically, this is what I want to happen. 1. close the stream 2. If the stream has close do something (e.g. update the database). I can just do the above right?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a function returns a value comparable to bool ([fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) returns boolean) it'l work, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

```
// this doesn't make much sense, because you already closed a stream
fclose($stream); //return true
if (fclose($stream)) { // will return false because resource already closed
    // do something 
};
```